# regex for find xml tags in text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to find one item (`<book>`) in the following xml.  Can someone help me with this?

Example:

```
    <books>
     <book> 
        <author>data</author>
        <name>data</name>
     </book>
     <book> 
       <author>data</author>
       <name>data</name>
     </book>
    </books>
```

Result:

```
    <book><author>data</author><name>data</name></book>
    <book><author>data</author><name>data</name></book>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is you want to do.

Comment: `s~</?books>~~g` and `s/\r?\n//g`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <books>
        <book>
            <author>data</author>
            <name>data</name>
        </book>
        <book>
            <author>data</author>
            <name>data</name>
        </book>
    </books>', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

$output = '';
foreach($xml as $i){
    $output .= $i->asXML();
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the following regex with a null:

```
((?<!</book>) *\r\n *|(?<=^|\r\n).*</?books>\r\n)
```